# IAP.getProducts getting empty response

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase

1. In agreement & tax status is active
2. In app purchase product id status is ready to submit
   Tried with two product Id's one is Non-Renewing Subscription & for consumable
   May I have to submit app for review then I will get response in IAP.getProducts?

Comment: Are you testing on a simulator or a real device?

Comment: Tested in both real device & simulator